# What's the Security issue involved in this file

Tags: linux, shell, access-control

I got a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#file name : eg.1 
X=$1
eval "$X"
```

if I launch this script as a group user or others user, is there any security concern raised?

Comment: It all depends on what the argument to this script is. Is this the entire script? It seems a bit pointless.

Comment: yes, it is, i am wondering if i feed any malicious parameter when i sh it, will any security issue be made to the system.

Comment: could u give an example if its possible thx

Answer (score 0):

The `eval` command is extremely powerful and extremely easy to abuse.
It causes your code to be parsed twice instead of once; this means that, for example, if your code has variable references in it, the shell's parser will evaluate the contents of that variable. If the variable contains a shell command, the shell might run that command, whether you wanted it to or not. This can lead to unexpected results, especially when variables can be read from untrusted sources.

## Example

```
# This code is evil and should never be used!
fifth() {
_fifth_array=$1
eval echo "\"The fifth element is \${$_fifth_array[4]}\""    # DANGER!
}
a=(zero one two three four five)
fifth a
```

output

```
fifth 'x}"; date; #'
```

> The fifth element is
> Thu Mar 27 16:13:47 EDT 2014
> [more details](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

Comment: can I use this file to achieve elevation of privilege, for example, can I access a file that I don't have permission to access by using that eg.1

Comment: @VinceFIT, no. Unlike Windows Linux is a secure against such attack. What danger is an attacker can execute commands at your privillage. For example they can execute `rm` to delete your personal data, touch to create infinite files filling your partition which in turn lead to DoS and sometimes make the system unbootable.